# Including js / images / css in codeigniter + google app engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

If anyone has got a running CodeIgniter application on app engine, please help me I am stuck here, on `.yaml` with including `css`, `js`, `images` 
my folder structure is:

```
-- codeigniter2.1.3 
|---- application
  |---- assets
      |---- images
      |---- js
      |---- css
      |---- uploads
-- app.yaml
```

I dont know if my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Assume you want to mimic Apache (or similar) like behavior and serve them from a URL path the same as directory structure. If so you just need to tell app engine the location of static assets.

```
- url: /application/assets
  static_dir: application/assets
```

Alternatively, one can list out extensions in a regex approach.

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: /\1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```